# Square Connect App Responding with 200 code and 0 Items

Tags: api, square-connect

I have two Square accounts I actively retrieve and push data to. I have created a third account that I setup with an App name and Personal Access Token.

Currently, I have a script in PHP and CURL to manually retrieve all the items of new account and print them to the page. (Very simple for now).

Once I open the page, I receive a 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' response, however, there are no items printed on the page.

My headache - I change **ONLY** the Personal Access Token to one of my previous accounts that I use with Square Up, open the page, and it returns all the  items for that account!

Is there any parameter that I am missing in setting up the new App in connect.squareup.com for the new account? I am using the Basic setup with an 'Application Name' and a Square generated 'Personal Access Token.' Why won't the account respond with any items?

Comment: Two questions: 

1. Are you sure your account has items in it? (seems silly to ask, but I might as well)

2. If you hit the `/v1/me` [Retrieve Merchant endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-merchant) with the access token that's showing no items, what shows up in the `account_type` field?

Comment: 1. I do have items in the account. We use it everyday for register sales. I thought about saying this when posting originally to be clear - but thought it would seem silly.   2. "account_type":"BUSINESS", however, my other account that shows items is "account_type":"LOCATION".

Answer (score 1):

See: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/square-business-structure/

Business entities don't have items. Only locations have items.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1-business/#get-items

Hit /v1/locations, retrieve the location-id.
Then hit /v1/location-id/items
(Replacing "location-id" with the ID from the list locations response).

Comment: Thank you mike for pointing out that documentation. I don't remember setting up anything special for the other business, so how do I convert/add/other to change the 'account_type' to 'LOCATION?  There is currently an active location under my Square account in the Dashboard - how do I tell the API to connect with that location? I tried creating a new location and deactivating the old location with no luck where 'account_type' is still 'BUSINESS'. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can get a list of the business's locations with the [list locations endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-locations). Each one has a unique ID. Then, instead of hitting `/v1/me/items` or `/v1/merchant-id/items` you need to hit `/v1/location-id/items` (replacing "location-id" with the ID from the list items response).

I don't work on the API team anymore but I'll see what I can do about making the items docs a bit clearer.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for clearing that up. I'm starting to wonder how my other accounts are working when I know I am not specifying the 'location-id' specifically.

Comment: There are two kinds of accounts at Square. Simple accounts (the fast majority) are just a location, with no business entity. That means they'll "just work" because the location's items are the account's items. The multi-location BUSINESS type accounts are different, because some things (business information, for example) live on the business level, but most things are still scoped to the location. The docs about multi-location do a good job of explaining this, but it's something we're aware can be difficult and we (at Square, not me specifically) working to improve the experience.